# Parse.com query on custom column on Installation from .NET parse library

Tags: c#, parse-platform

On the Installation Class I have added two new columns `ContactID` and `UserEmail` as my need.

Now when sending push notification, I want to query with certain `ContactID` or `UserEmail`.

Push function provided by the **parse.dll** is as follows:

```
SendAlertAsync(string alert, ParseQuery<ParseInstallation> query);
```

The `ParseInstallation` class has predefined properties. How can I add my two new properties and build a ParseQuery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the answer here

https://parse.com/docs/dotnet/guide#push-notifications-using-advanced-targeting

```
var push = new ParsePush();
push.Query = from installation in ParseInstallation.Query
             where installation.Get<int>("ContactID") == 12
             select installation;
push.Alert = "Willie Hayes injured by own pop fly.";
await push.SendAsync();
```

or

```
await ParsePush.SendAlertAsync("Hi this is test message", new ParseQuery<ParseInstallation>()
                .Where(i => i.Get<string>("UserEmail") == "abc@gmail.com"));
```